# how to get data from two different db but table name is same in cakephp 2.5?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have 2 tables **data source** in cakephp:

1. **Default**
2. is **test**

Now in both db
**usermaster** same named table is available.

Now I need both db table user it is possible to get using **cakephp 2.5**?

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can create two models and bind the first one to default connection using $useDbConfig property of model and the other to the test connection and then define the table name for each model using the $useTable property of the model and use them as normal models

```
class MyTableInDefault extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'Default';
    public $useTable = 'MyTable';
}

class MyTableInTest extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'Test';
    public $useTable = 'MyTable';
}
```

not tested but should work perfectly